# Why doesn't the 802.11 standard implement TLS for wireless handshakes between clients and routers?

Tags: tls, wifi

Why aren't wireless handshakes sent using TLS?  It seems like it would be relatively simple to implement, perhaps having the vendor insert the private key into the routers.  That way WPA/WPA2/WEP encryption couldn't be cracked by capturing parts of the handshake sent in plain text.

Comment: WPA2 only vulnerable in that way when using TKIP.  Adding TLS to the wireless handshake would mean that each client would have to generate a certificate.  Or users would have to have a username and password to authenticate to the wireless access point.  This seems unnecessary, and using WPA2-PSK AES is more than adequate.

Comment: Isn't this just EAP-TLS?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#EAP-TLS

Comment: That's what first came to mind.  How is PKI implemented in EAP-TLS?

Comment: Identity authentication is via certificates and a RADIUS server. For everything you need to know see section 4.2.1 of the following document: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/secursw/ps2086/products_white_paper09186a008009256b.shtml#wp34608

Comment: From a pragmatic standpoint: “client-side certificate requires a PKI server infrastructure (rare for most organizations) to be in place ahead of time or 
expensive third-party certificates, it automatically excluded EAP-TLS as a feasible option for most 
organizations” (Ou, 2005).

Comment: @JamesR That's true, if you wanted to implement PKI with self signed certificates or have an internal CA it's an issue.  But what about creating a public PKI infrastructure just for routers?  Establish a chain of trust outside what's used for websites.

Comment: The certificates aren't necessarily issue there. In TLS, authentication by certificates is optional for both server and client. TLS would be just a channel established by two unknown parties not authenticated to each other. They would have to mutually authenticate. In TLS replacement of WPA2-PSK, they would have to mutually prove knowledge of the password without actual revealing it (e.g. Sociallist millionaire problem) and without a possibility to replay it. This might increase number of round-trips (compared to actual WPA2-PSK), but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

SSL relies in TCP/IP. TCP/IP relies on the physical and data link layer to have been established.  WiFi is part of physical and data link layers.  The idea being that you need the lower level links to be established before you can carry on a conversation at the high level.

It's a little like asking why can't a distant person who's only reachable by radio communicate the frequency to listen on in english.  Because to communicate in english, you first have to have a radio link, which means knowing the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all TLS is on a totally DIFFERENT [OSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) level than 802.11
802.11 is on layer 2, TLS is on layer 3/4/5 (it has a few parts) so you simple can not use it in this manner. and modifying it for that purpose is just as hard as creating (what they have done) a new one.

The handshake is not send in 'plaintext', its semi-ciphered. (similarly as how a RSA handshake works). the only reason it's "crackable" is because you always end up with a system that can be cracked. (you have to yield to much information to the environment) the only method to prevent it is by using more aggressive cipher switching (costs a lot more computational power, and limits bandwidth).

EAP-TLS works on a later state than when the handshake between router / client happens) (layer 3/4)

just adding 'crytoware' to a line does NOT mean its more secure. and having it work for all devices is a problem that is still not fully solved.